# Email notification if any ssis package fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

We schedule jobs in production environment, on daily basis 24/7. Every time we need to check the status of the jobs whether it was completed or failed, we have to execute the query.

I want to reduce the manual work, by creating a package which runs every 15 mins to check the status of the loads. If there's any failure it has to send email notification.

We created a log table, which logs package name, starttime, endtime, and status of the job.

So let me know if there's any approach for this.

Comment: SQL jobs do have an option to notify completion of the job(either success or failure), you can set operator there in order to get notified.

Answer (score 1):

The send mail taks in SSIS will do this job wonderfully for you.

The MSDN article is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142165.). Create a master package with a 'execute package' task. Configure that task to run the package the package that you are running. Then set up a send mail task as you wish. set the precedent contstraint to run from the execute package task to the send mail task. Right click that constraint and change to failure

This will then replace your existing package, and when run will send an email if the task fails.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure Database Mail as shown [here](http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/desiree/how-to-set-up-database-mail-for-sql-server-job-failures/) then create an operator to notify you when the job fails or succeeds.

Other approach can be configure SSIS Package Event Handler to notify you if Onerror Event is triggered. Check the following images:

[image]

You have to create a SMTP connection and use it in Send Mail Task:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can find a lot of tutorials/blog posts about this if you search for it. Some examples:

[Link 1](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/setting-up-email-notification-for-ssis-package-failure.html)

[Link 2](http://bimentalist.com/2011/05/24/ssis-custom-logging-using-event-handlers-and-sql-server-job-scheduling/)

Our approach to this was to have a single parent SSIS package in the job that will run all the other child packages and that has on the OnPostExecute Event Handler a SQL Task in case of failure that will trigger a stored procedure sending the e-mails with the details of the failure.